# CUDN_STATUS_BAD_PARAM:Cnn in matlab

Tags: matlab, cudnn

I am currently trying to train and test a network in matlab using cnn using gpu. I have gpu -GTX 1070 and CUDA 8.0 and cudnn 5.1. 
I followed the example of object detection using deep learning provided by mathworks from the link
https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/object-detection-using-deep-learning.html
After I run the following lines:

```
        % Train a network.
        Net1 = trainNetwork(trainingImages, trainingLabels, layers, opts);
```

It is giving me the trained network as output. But after I run the following line

```
        YTest = predict(Net1, X_test);
```

it is giving me following error

```
    Error using nnet.internal.cnngpu.convolveForward2D
Unexpected error calling cuDNN: CUDNN_STATUS_BAD_PARAM.

Error in nnet.internal.cnn.layer.Convolution2D/doForward (line 218)
            Z = nnet.internal.cnngpu.convolveForward2D( ...

Error in nnet.internal.cnn.layer.Convolution2D/forwardNormal (line 195)
            Z = this.doForward(X,this.Weights.Value,this.Bias.Value);

Error in SeriesNetwork/predict (line 139)
                Y(:,:,:,i) = predictNetwork.predict(X);
```

Comment: I would imagine that 90% of this code is not relevant to your question.  Please create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: Have edited the question. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For a Pascal card you need to get the cuDNN patch:
https://www.mathworks.com/support/bugreports/1439741

Comment: I have already tried this.But it is still giving the same error.